# How to estimate the average surface temperature of a planet?

Tags: planets, climate, solar-system, temperature

If given:

- Planet mass
- Planet radius
- Planet orbital distance (perihelion and aphelion)
- Planet albedo
- Planet atmospheric composition
- Planet atmospheric pressure
- Star mass
- Star luminosity

Is there any way to estimate the surface temperature of the planet? I know of the equilibrium temperature, but that doesn't take into account the atmosphere, and therefore doesn't fit what I want it to do. I also know of some simple greenhouse models, but those seem to only take into account carbon dioxide, while my atmospheres could have multiple possible greenhouse gases.

Comment: The best way is to ask on https://astronomy.stackexchange.com/

Comment: I concur. Be sure to take their tour and read up in their help centre about how to post an on-topic question *before* you post it.

Comment: Sorry. I wasn't sure where the best place to post this was, I saw similar posts on this stackexchange so I thought it would fit.

Comment: Hello Empika, welcome to [worldbuilding.se]. You're asking a deceptively simple question about the most complex aspect of worldbuilding: climate. You're missing a lot of variables including percentage and distribution of landmass, average height above sea level of the landmass, salinity of the ocean water, percentage of fresh vs. salt water. Atmospheric composition must include humidity, average wind velocities at the equator and the poles (at least), and average particulate count. Average cloud cover and average precipitation. Planetary rotational velocity, etc. etc., etc., (\*continued\*)

Comment: I guess my point is, you're looking for a scientifically accurate answer to a problem so complex that humanity can't actually do it by mathematical model but instead uses land-based sensors, ocean-based sensors, and satellites... then averages the results. So while you could ask this on [astronomy.se] or [earthscience.se], it's kinda unlikely that you're going to get the kind of answer you're looking for. This Q falls into my, "why do you need to know to that level of detail?" category of questions - because the precision of the answer won't improve whatever it is your doing.

Comment: There are resources for some of the "harder" science fiction roleplaying games (eg some editions of Traveller) for this kind of thing but the ones I have seen will not account for all possible variables, more of a first order approximation.  (If you do look at these, make sure when you plug in values for Earth that the result is in the ballpark - at least one I encountered had major typos.)  As stated by @JBH there is no simple formula that will allow accurate calculation.